# How can I pre-install self-signed USB drivers on Windows XP?

Tags: installation, windows-xp, usb, driver

I'm trying to get some USB drivers for medical devices pre-installed on our corporate workstations. Unfortunately, these drivers are not signed. Based on some research done here and elsewhere, I self-signed these drivers using a certificate that I created:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Self Root CA" -b 01/01/2006 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.6 -sv selfcert.pvk selfcert.cer
```

I added the certificate to the "Trusted Root CA" and "Trusted Publishers CA" and and signed the drivers:

```
signtool sign /f selfcert.pfx /p password /uw /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /v C:\gendex\fusiondexis.cat
```

I added the '/uw' parameter because the "Windows System Component Verification" (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.6) and "Code Signing" (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3) are present in the certificate, thus it seemed appropriate.

I then verified the signatures with signtool:

```
signtool.exe verify /pa /v /c C:\gendex\fusiondexis.cat C:\gendex\fusiondexis.inf
```

The driver files were copied to 'C:\gendex' and I updated the registry key 'DevicePath' to include this path when searching for driver files. However, when I plug-in the device, Windows displays the Add New Hardware Wizard which requires an admin to enter their credentials. If I don't do that, the device remains in an unrecognized state, and if I do--it works fine.

I've been banging my head trying to figure this out all day. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you added `selfcert.cer` (Self Root CA) to local machine store and not to the user specific store. You can use

```
CertMgr.exe -add -c selfcert.cer -s -r localMachine AuthRoot
```

I deviloped the solution for one my customer about 8 years ago and it still work. I used at the time old version of SignTool which doesn't had /uw switch. I used just

```
SignTool.exe signwizard /v LXT52Xxp.cat
```

For the troubleshooting I would recommend you to set detailed SetupAPI log (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). It will shows whether which drives from which directory will be get and whether the ranking of the driver will be interpreted the same as "Microsoft signed".

Comment: Actually I guess I did everything right. The only reason why it didn't work was that Windows had an old copy of the files in its driver store (INF and PNF in C:\WINDOWS\inf and CAT in C:\WINDOWS\system32\CatRoot\{...}). Once I deleted these files, Windows retrieved the correct files from C:\gendex and put them in the driver store... and it worked! Thanks for your help, Oleg! This is going to save me and my department a lot of work.